# Описание полей файла packege.json создаваемого командой npm init?

Tags: npm

За что отвечает поле `entry point` и `test command`? и есть ли хорошее описание этого файла на русском языке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entry point` - или если по-русски "точка входа" это файл `javascript` который будет вызываться, когда пользователи "требуют" его, т.е. этот файл будет включать в себя основную логику для Вашего приложения/модуля. Грубо говоря, просто исполняемый файл с кодом.

`test command` - это команда, которая запускается всякий раз, когда Вы вызываете `npm test`
попробуйте вызвать команду `npm test` Вы должны увидеть сообщение(по умолчанию):

> Error: no test specified

Как правило, данная команда является тестировщиком, типа: `mocha`, `ava` и т.д.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что для использования `grunt` его можно оставить по дефолту?

Comment: @doox911, Да, всё верно. Оставить как заглушку, так сказать.